# Mapsui Xamarin Forms center map

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapsui

I'm using Mapsui 2.0-beta.22 and Xamarin Forms 3.4.0 for my app. I can't get map centering work, I have tried many examples from stack, other sites and Mapsui examples.

The only "available" method for me is:

`map.Home = n => n.NavigateTo(sphericalMercatorCoordinate, map.Resolutions[9]);`

from examples, as Mapsui version I'm using does not have methods in Map class to center view.

I was trying to center map from `MapViewModel` method:

```
public async override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
```

and I was passing Point coords in NavigationParameters, then used them to 
create `sphericalMercatorCoordinate`. Even if the point is valid, using `NavigateTo` from above is not working in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map.Home method is meant to specify the initial viewport. If you want to zoom to any viewport or location after initialization you need to use:

```cs
mapControl.Navigator.NavigateTo
```

Comment: Thanks. What should `NavigateTo` first argument point to? Tried longitude/latitude, also tried WorldToScreen and the only thing that changes is zoom.

Comment: Forgot to add spherical mercator, now it navigates to the point I wanted :) Thanks a lot.